# Playing ringtones from a string/SQlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I'm using a sqlite database to allow the user to store ringtone that will sound at the end of a timer.
`if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_ring) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
        }`

The result of this activity is converted into a string. The ringtones are stored in a format like:    **content://media/internal/audio/media/43**

I want to play this ringtone at the end of a CountDownTimer, but I don't know how point the RingToneManager to this resource.

How would you approach playing a ringtone stored in this format?

Edit Solution:

If the ringtone is stored in String sound, you can set Ringtone r to:

`r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(sound));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is a content `Uri`. `RingtoneManager` has a [`getRingtone(Context, Uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#getRingtone(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) that returns a `Ringtone`, which has a [`play()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html#play()) method.